# Codimension in families

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, krull-dimension

I’m trying to get my head around the concept of codimension of schemes. If everything is a variety it’s easier to understand the intuition.  I thought of the following question which I don’t have a good intuition for:

Suppose we have a closed immersion $Z \to X$ over a scheme $S$. I want to think of this as a family of closed subschemes $Z_s \subset X_s$ as $s\in S$ varies.

**The Question**

What can we say about the function $codim_{X_s}(Z_s)$ in $s$? Especially, how does it relate to the global codimension $codim_X(Z)$? The latter is what I find most difficult to grasp intuitively.

I’m happy to make simplifying hypotheses on $S$. I believe that everything is constant if $X$ and $Z$ are both flat over $S$. I am happy to assume $X$ is flat over $S$ but I think my question will be more interesting if $Z$ is not assumed flat over $S$. I might want to assume that $X$ is biequidimensional or something like that, I think.

Examples of how things can be weird even if simple examples would also be very welcome!

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  You might like the following (mostly expository) article of Brian Osserman.  It applies to stacks as well as schemes, but he collects many illuminating examples already for schemes: https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6328